# Rendering of a template exception

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I installed SonataClassificationBundle and extend it on my App\Application folder. The documentation on the official website isn't clear [Classification Bundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/classification/3-x/doc/reference/classification_types.html)

I corrected all namespaces to point into my extended bundle. I cleared the cache without error and I run the server.

When I log into the profile, I get this exception :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "admin_app_sonataclassificationcategory_create" as such route does not exist.").
```

There is my sonata_classification:

```
sonata_classification:
    class:
        category: App\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category
        collection: App\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Collection
        context: App\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Context
        tag: App\Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Tag
```

I detected the same problem with SonataUserBundle, but after promoting my user to ROLE_ADMIN, the problem was solved.

Can someone help?

Thank you

Comment: Can you try to run the command : "php bin/console debug:router admin_app_sonataclassificationcategory_create" to see if the corresponding route exists or not ?

Comment: @Stephan I just found this route admin_sonata_classification_category_create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved again.
I just run :

```
composer update
```